# Make own strrchr() function but case-insensitiv

Tags: c, char, c-strings, function-definition, strrchr

my exercise is to create my own strrchr() function in c.

My solution is a loop. I'am counting the array length. I will input this number into the for loop. For example: With the input Hello. I will go from right to left to search for a letter.

What's not working is the return part.

My code returns the following with the input Hello, and search letter l. lo. That's not what I need. My ouput should be lleH.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

```
    char *KULstrrcichr(char *arr, char search)

// The strrchr() function returns a pointer to the last occurrence of the character c in the string s.
{   
    int stringcnt;
    stringcnt = strlen(arr);
    printf("%d\n", stringcnt);
    search = tolower(search);
    for (int i = stringcnt-1; arr[i]; i--)
    {
        arr[i] = tolower(arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = stringcnt-1; arr[i]; i--)
    {
        if (search == arr[i])
        {
            return &arr[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Okay I found out that my code works as expected...

Comment: Again, don't post and repost the same question over and over. That will only lead to fewer people wanting to help you!

Comment: You should probably also take some time to sit down and actually *think* about your assignment, and the problems you have. As well as learning how to *debug* your own code (which is an essential thing to know for all programmers).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but this is a new functions. I found a solution to my old one. It's exactly this code but in the other direction from left to right.

Comment: Then rename the question, make the title a short summary of the problem you actually ask about. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And [edit] your question to tell us the expected behavior and the actual behavior (preferably with examples of input and actual versus expected output). And please try to create a [mre] to show us how you call the function.

Comment: Also note that the real [`strrchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) function doesn't reverse the string! So searching for the last `'l'` in the string `"Hello"` should return the string `"lo"`.

Comment: `for (int i = stringcnt-1; arr[i]; i--)`: when  does this loop stop? Think again.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the loop stops when the length of the string is 0.

Comment: @TheLuckyGuy wrong, the loop stops when `arr[i]`  is 0. Ask yourself what happens once `i` is 0.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude after looking into it again it works as expected.

Comment: @TheLuckyGuy another issue in your code: `arr[i] = tolower(arr[i]);` actually modifies the original string, and I'm pretty sure it shouldn't. For that reason `KULstrrcichr("Hello", 'e')` won't work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the excercise says that it has to be case-insensitive thats why I'am converting.

Comment: @TheLuckyGuy being case insensitive is one thing. Permanently converting the original string to lower case is another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard C function `strrchr` is declared the following way

```
char *strrchr(const char *s, int c);
```

That is it first parameter has the qualifier `const` and the second parameter is of the type `int`. It means that you may not change the source string.

Also this for loop

```
for (int i = stringcnt-1; arr[i]; i--)
```

invokes undefined behavior due to the incorrect condition.

The function can be defined the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * my_strrchr( const char *s, int c )
{
    c = tolower( ( unsigned char )c );

    const char *p = s + strlen( s ) + 1;

    while (p != s && tolower( ( unsigned char )p[-1] ) != c) --p;

    return p == s ? NULL : ( char * )( p - 1 );
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "helLo";

    char *p = my_strrchr( s, 'l' );

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        printf( "position = %td, substring = %s\n", p - s, p );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
position = 3, substring = Lo
```